# Recalc Pivot Table with Basic API

Tags: calc, libreoffice-basic, openoffice-basic

To update pivot tables I use uno with this instruction:

```
dispatcher.executeDispatch(monDocUno, ".uno:RecalcPivotTable", "", 0, Array())
```

I would like not to use uno but the basic and its API to recalculate the pivot table of a calc sheet.

How we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [**.refresh()**](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XDataPilotTable.html#refresh) method:

```
Sub refreshAllPilotTables
Dim oSheets As Variant
Dim oSheet As Variant
Dim oDataPilotTables As Variant
Dim oPilotTable As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
    oSheets = ThisComponent.getSheets()
    For i = 0 To oSheets.getCount()-1
        oSheet = oSheets.getByIndex(i)
        oDataPilotTables = oSheet.getDataPilotTables()
        For j = 0 To oDataPilotTables.getCount()-1
            oPilotTable = oDataPilotTables.getByIndex(j)
            oPilotTable.refresh()
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok thank you so much JohnSun. I had tested ` oDoc.Calculate` method but it didn’t work!